# Format Specifier and Pointers in C give unexpected result

Tags: c, pointers

```
char *s = "Hi";
printf("%s",s);
```

`s` here is a pointer, I set the datatype to `"%s"`, the output is "Hi", the string.

```
int a = 1;
int *p = &a;
printf("%i", p);
```

`p` here is also a pointer, I set the datatype to `"%i"`, why the output is not "1", the integer?

In the two cases, if I set the datatypes to `"%p"`, they both will give me the address of the variable. But if I set the datatypes to the datatype of the variables, why they do not both give the content of the variables store?

Comment: It's just the way the language is defined: `%s` for printing a null terminated string given by a pointer to the first character, `%i` is for integer values, and `%p` is for the address a pointer holds. Since `p` is not an integer type (but a pointer), you cannot print the value it points to with `%i`.

Comment: Rather, it's just the way this family of functions is defined. I wouldn't recommend anyone to dig too deep into all the details of `stdio.h` - that header is solely for quick & dirty console I/O like learning or debug printing, it shouldn't be used for other purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Explanation

##### String

A string is an array of `char`, this is why strings are typed as `char*` in C.

When a string ends, a special character is used, `\0`, you do not have to type this character, as C and most other programming languages will add it automatically.

So, when you type `char* s = "Hi";`, C is storing an array like so: `["H", "i", "\0"]` somewhere in your RAM. The value `s` is now a pointer to the first element of the array (`"H"`). You can test this by running `printf("%c", *s)`.

When typing `printf("%s", s)` you are specifying that you want to print a string because you are using `"%s"`, so C will start to print out characters from whatever `s` is pointing at until it finds a `\0`.

##### int

In the case of `int`, you are storing an `int` and then you store its address using `p`. When you execute `printf("%i", p)`, C prints the value of `p`, a memory address.

If you wanted to print out the `int` that is pointed at by `p`, you would need to execute something like `printf("%d", *p)`, this specifies that I want to print out an `int` because I'm using `"%d"`, and the integer is whatever `p` is pointing at, so I dereference the pointer `p` (`*p`).

---

#### Code snippet

Try running this to see if you get it!

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char *s = "Hi";
    printf("Print the address of the string: %i\n", s);
    printf("Print the whole string: %s\n", s);

    // s is a pointer to 'H'
    printf("Print the address of 'H': %i\n", s);
    printf("Print 'H': %c\n", *s);

    // If s points to 'H', then s+1 points to 'i'
    printf("Print the address of 'i': %i\n", s+1);
    printf("Print 'i': %c\n", *(s+1));

    // Then there should be a \0 after 'i'
    printf("Print the address of '\\0': %i\n", s+1);
    printf("Print '\\0' (You shouldn't see anything): %c\n", *(s+2));

    int i = 1;
    int* p = &i;
    printf("Print the address of i: %i\n", p);
    printf("Print i: %d\n", *p);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"When you execute `printf("%i", p)`, C prints the value of p, a memory address."_ - Perhaps. It has undefined behavior so it could just as well just crash.

Comment: Why are you spamming unrelated book recommendations in your answer? That book seems to be from 1994? That's very outdated.

Comment: I bought the book a year ago or so, it's what I used to get started on C. I know it is kind of outdated but it's the one that worked best for me, it managed to give me the notion I needed to learn C and to improve. I wasn't really trying to spam it, I found it helpful and thought that maybe other people starting out would too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int a = 1;
int *p = &a;
printf("%p\n", p);
printf("%d\n", *p);
```

`p` is `pointer` that type is `int*`, print should with `%p`, if you want to get `1` that is `int` type, you need to use `*p` to get value that type is `int`.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the datatype to `%s`, the `printf`function expects a pointer to a null-terminated character array (i.e., a C-style string), and it will print the characters pointed to by s until it encounters a null terminator ('\0'). So, it correctly prints "Hi" because "Hi" is a null-terminated string.

In other words, it works because `%s` is specifically designed to expect a pointer to a null-terminated character array. In `C` a string is exactly that (a null-terminated character array). When you provide the pointer `s` to `%s`, `printf` interprets it as the starting address of a character array in memory and then prints the characters at that address until it reaches a null terminator ('\0'). String literals in `C` (like "Hi") are automatically null-terminated by the compiler, so when you declare

```
char *s = "Hi";
```

`s` is pointing to the first character of the "Hi" string, and `%s` in `printf` correctly interprets it as a string.

When you set the datatype to `%i`, you're telling `printf` to expect an integer, but you're passing a pointer to an integer, not an integer directly. This will result in undefined behaviour because `printf` is interpreting the pointer as an integer, not dereferencing it to get the value pointed to by `p`. The output is not "1" because it's printing the value of the pointer itself (address) rather than the content of the integer it points to. If you want to get the value that `p` points to you need to dereference the pointer by using an asterix:

```c
printf("%i", *p);
```

When you use `%p` as the format specifier, `printf` expects a pointer, and it will correctly print the address of the variable being pointed to (`s` and `a`).